# How can i determine binary files are not corrupted in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

Currently I am stuck with the question as to how can I can decide , programmatically , whether a file ( binary , ZIP Or EXE etc.) is broken or not . I mean , how does Windows decide that the binary file is incomplete ?

Can someone guide me in the right direction ?
I am specifically looking for : ZIP & EXE

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with a case where Windows decides that a file is incomplete. Can you please provide some nor context to this question?

Comment: @RobKennedy : When you try to install some EXE ( incomplete ones) , the installation will fail . And when a broken archive file is opened , the winrar program shows "Broken" . How do they achieve it ?

Comment: Cyprus, I'm reading the discussion you're having in the comments, and it looks as if your actual question is: "How can I determine in my program that a binary file is not corrupted?"  If so, please edit your question and include *what* binary files you want to check.

Answer (score 7):

ZIP files (as well as many other archive formats) contain a checksum (e.g. CRC32) that allows to verify the integrity of file. PE header (for .exe files) contains sizes of file sections which also allow to perform some checks.

In common case, there is no means to verify integrity of a binary file unless there is some additional information about the file (and it can be built in the file itself). CRC32 code and also MD5 or SHA1 hashes are frequently used to check whether the file is corrupted or not.

Comment: Ok, you mean to say that the CRC32 included for each file is included by the server ? But the CRC32 is present for each seperate file . How can i do something for the whole file ?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand the question. I would protect each file with its own checksum: one checksum per file. Although there are applications where several parts of a file have their own checksums (this allows to access these parts independently and verify only the needed parts). One can imagine a common checksum for a bunch of files, but this doesn't seem to be convenient. As for where the checksums should be stored - one may integrate them directly into the protected file (header or footer), or keep a separate file with checksum(s).

Comment: That's not what it means at all, Cyprus. I don't know what "server" you're talking about. Some file formats include a checksum for the file. Calculate the checksum of a file, and compare it to the stored value. If they match, then the file is probably OK. If not, then there's something wrong with the file.

Comment: @Inspired : I have found a PAS file which calculates the CRC of a file here :http://read.pudn.com/downloads9/sourcecode/math/34631/crc32.pas__.htm.  Now this will calculate the CRC of full archive . How can i verify the file integrity with this ?

Comment: So do you want to verify a single file inside some archive? This is an archive-specific task, you should know the archive's format. Basically it's unpacking the file from archive, calculating its checksum and comparing it with the checksum recorded for this file in the archive's header. If you have a ZIP archive then you'd better find a library that handles ZIP; such a library should be able to check an integrity of files being verified/unpacked.